# Custom exception for wcf services with Single Concurrency Mode

Tags: wcf, concurrency

I have one Operation on a wcf service which can be executed by only one request at the time.
I can easily achieve it using the Single concurrency mode, anyway other operations on the service can be executed simultaneously and, more important, I wouldn't like my client to wait for the timeout exception, but I would like to throw a specific exception.

Which is the best way to implement it? Should I use a static object to lock the critical section? Any other techniques?

Comment: Exactly under what circumstances do you want to throw the custom exception?

Comment: The operation is executed asynchronously and it could take a couple of minutes.
I don't want the other clients to wait the timeout to get the exception, but I would like to get it immediately since I know that the service is "locked" for that operation.

Comment: But if it's single concurrency mode, the other clients will never reach the service. There will be no opportunity for the service to throw the custom exception.

Comment: I  wouldn't like to use the single concurrency mode. All other operations can be done concurrently.
Only one operation is critical for concurrency, and I would like all other clients to know that it is already 'locked'.
PS: thanks for you attempt to support.